# How to check content file for existence?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I have .mp4 file as content. How can I check if I realy have it in my application?

**Update**
for example in my case I have source: `/res/9a8be1550f818223edcfc5ab6d765cec.mp4`

```
if (File.Exists(localPath))
{
    myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(localPath, UriKind.Relative);
}
```

if I check this way there is an exception:

Comment: You "have it"? It's not clear whether you have it in isolated storage or only embedded in your project.

Comment: if its attached as a content, it is there or you are not doing it right. shouldn't have to check it.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo sr;  
sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("images/MenuIcon.png", UriKind.Relative)); // path should NOT begin with a slash  
if (sr == null)  
{  
    // doesn't exist  
}  
else  
{  
    // exists  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer from user "revolutionkpi" can caused System.IO.IOException, better is add try-catch block:**

```
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo sr; 
try {
    sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/images/MenuIcon.png",UriKind.Relative));
    if (sr == null)  {  
        // doesn't exist  
    }
    else{  
        // exists  
    } 
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // doesn't exist
}
```

Edit1: *more pretty solution*

```
var uri = new Uri("/images/MenuIcon.png", UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource image = null;

try
{
    if (Application.GetResourceStream(uri) != null)
    {
        image = new BitmapImage(uri); 
    } 
}
catch { }

if (image == null) {
    // doesn't exist  
}
```

Comment: Have you seen his comment `// path should NOT begin with a slash`?

Comment: I tried path `"/images/MenuIcon.png"` and `"images/MenuIcon.png"` and both caused *System.IO.IOException*